# How to store attributes of a large shapefile in a list?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am trying to store the attributes of a shapefile into a list. With following code it works for smaller shapes:

```
addA = []
While provider.nextFeature(feat):
    attrs = feat.attributeMap()
    for (k,attr) in attrs.iteritems():
        addA.append(attr.toString())
```

If I try to store a large shape my pc runs out of memory or freezes. I tried to put the attributes in a blist and in a numpy array, but nothing really worked (or probably I did not understand how to set up a proper numpy array...). Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to put it on a list btw? Maybe there would be some solutions that won't require you to put it on a list.

Comment: i want to do a comparisson between the attributes of two shapes. Therfore i want to save the attributes in a list and compare the lists. It is possible to select the attributes for certain fields, that only the requireded attributes are stored in the list. But this step freezes qgis as well.

Comment: Only the attributes change then? The geometries are constant?

Comment: I need only the attributes. The geometries are constant.

Comment: I iterated over all the attributes it counts 13050810 with a time of 39,92 sec. Probably the data is too big to store into a normal list?

Answer (score 3):

It is not a problem of numpy arrays or other things, it's a problem of garbage collection. Each time you create a list, everything is stored in memory and if the list is big.... So you need to know Python (and not only PyQGIS) and the tricks to get out ("big data problem", you should reduce memory usage and use algorithms that do not slow down the process):

**First: do not use a while loop (see [While loop](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)):**

> "**While loops**, like the For Loop, are used for repeating sections of code - 
>       but unlike a for loop, the while loop will not run n times, 
>       but until a defined condition is met. As the for loop in Python is so powerful, 
>       while **is rarely used, except in cases where a user's input is required**"

which is not the case here and it slows things due to first testing the True condition every loop.

If you want to process all data in a layer in QGIS 1.8 (not necessary in master version which allows any process, even if the elements of a layer are not selected).

```
def select_all(layer):
    # select all elements of a layer, geometry and attributes
    layer.select([])
    layer.setSelectedFeatures([obj.id() for obj in layer])

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
select_all(layer)
```

And after

```
for elem in layer.selectedFeatures():
    geom= elem.geometry()
    attrs = elem.attributeMap()
```

and no more while loop !

**Secondly, if you only need the values of a dictionary, uses attrs.values() and  not  attrs.iteritems(), forcing the loop to go through all keys and values**

```
addA = []
for elem in layer.selectedFeatures():
    attrs = elem.attributeMap()
    for  value in attrs.values():
        addA.append(value.toString())
```

**Thirdly, you can use iterators, generators or list comprehension**, see [Python Generator Hacking](http://www.dabeaz.com/usenix2009/generators/GeneratorUSENIX.pdf):

List comprehension (can be used anywhere a sequence is expected)

what it means:

```
result = []
for x in s:
if condition:
    result.append(expression)
```

so:

```
addA = []
for elem in layer.selectedFeatures():
    attrs = elem.attributeMap()
    addA.append([value.toString() for value in attrs.values()])
```

**and if you want, you can construct a nested list comprehension for addA in one line (without using a preliminary empty list, saving memory):**

```
addA = [[value.toString() for value in elem.attributeMap().values()] for elem in macouche.selectedFeatures()]
```

> "This means that list comprehensions aren’t useful if you’re working with iterators that return an infinite stream or a very large amount of data. Generator expressions are preferable in these situations" ([functional Python](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html))

with Generators:

> A generator is a one-time operation. It does not construct a list and you can iterate over the generated data once, but if you want to do it again, you have to call the generator function again. Once consumed, it disappears from memory.

what it means (no list, return one value):

```
for x in s: 
   if condition:
       yield expression
```

so:

```
addA = []
for elem in layer.selectedFeatures():
     attrs = elem.attributeMap()
     generator =(value.toString() for value in attrs.values())
     print generator

 <generator object <genexpr> at 0x12bff6eb0>
  ....
```

Its purpose is only iteration:

```
addA = []
for elem in layer.selectedFeatures():
    attrs = elem.attributeMap()
    generator =(value.toString() for value in attrs.values())
    for i in generator:
        addA.append(i)
```

and with a huge savings in memory area:

```
addA = []
# generator
for i in ((value.toString() for value in elem.attributeMap().values()) for elem in  macouche.selectedFeatures()):
    for j in i:
         addA.append(j)
```

I hope this will help

Comment: You shouldn't use setSelectedFeatures unless you want to highlight them in the map. You only need layer.select()

Comment: FYI this is how you should do it https://gist.github.com/NathanW2/5659716

You are also not going to get good performance out of selectedFeatures() as that is returning a full list. (https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/src/core/qgsvectorlayer.cpp#L2660).

Comment: I'm sorry, but your solution (gist) does not work for me (in 1.8, empty list as result), without selecting the features first ( full list as result). I know the the 2.0 solution

Comment: Works for me in 1.8 using a plain shapefile. http://pastebin.com/A4KTvqbY